# Does logstash support If-Then-Else Conditionals in Regular Expressions?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, grok, logstash-grok

I tried to use follow regex: (a)?b(?(1)c|d). It is example from http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html.

But I got error.

```
/opt/logstash-1.4.2/bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } }  filter { grok { match => [ "message", "(a)?b(?(1)c|d)" ] } } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug }}'
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| An unexpected error occurred. This is probably a bug.   |
| You can find help with this problem in a few places:    |
|                                                         |
| * chat: #logstash IRC channel on freenode irc.          |
|     IRC via the web: http://goo.gl/TI4Ro                |
| * email: logstash-users@googlegroups.com                |
| * bug system: https://logstash.jira.com/                |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
The error reported is: 
  undefined group option: /(a)?b(?(1)c|d)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Logstash uses [Oniguruma Regular Expressions](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt).  Their doc says that this is a "Lacked features compare with perl 5.8.0".  So, no.